# Find & replace multiple keywords defined string

Tags: regex, string, replace

I'm trying to remove the following string/line in my SQL database:

```
<p><span style="font-size:16px"><strong>The quick brown &nbsp;</strong></span><strong><span style="font-size:16px">fox jumps.</span></strong></p>
```

1. String will always start with `<p>` and end with `</p>`
2. String will always contain these words, in the same order: `The`, `quick`, `brown`. But they might be separated by something else (space, `&nbsp;` or other HTML tags)
3. String is part of field with more text, nested HTML tags, so the solution must ignore higher level `<p></p>` tags.
4. We are talking about +20k matches, no manual edits solutions please :)

I have already tried doing it with RegExp but I can't filter for multiple keywords (`AND` operator).

I can export my DB to a sql file so I can use any solution you would recommend, Windows/Linux, text editor, js script etc. but I would appreciate the simplest and elegant solution.

Comment: Which SQL database? Are `The`, `quick` and `brown` always in same order? Do you want to remove the record, or just delete that text from the text of the field?

Comment: @Amadan that is MySQL

Comment: Can you show us how you used Regexp ?

Comment: @Elyasin `/<p.+The.+quick.+brown.+\/p>/;` But since there are nested html tags, this will capture highest level `<p></p>` thus removing more than necessary.

Comment: @FlorinC. Clarify this in your question. You are getting wrong answers this way.

Comment: @Amadan that string is part of more text being stored in that particular record. I would like to remove just that portion of text. Yes, the words always appear in the same order but might be separated by different things.

Comment: How many records/occurrences are we talking about? If it's a table with not too many records it might be safer/easier to use a very crude regex and then delete the text by hand.

Comment: @Jonathan we are talking about more than 20k matches :)

Comment: Then it's not possible in MySQL. Either transition to MariaDB which should be MySQL-compatible ("drop-in replacement") but has `REGEXP_REPLACE`, or export to CSV and do it in, say, Ruby (or any language with a good CSV library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to restrict `.*` by a non-efficient but more precise `(?:(?!<\/?p[^<]*>).)*` that will force to match the words inside 1 `<p>` tag:

```
(?i)<p>(?:(?!<\/?p[^<]*>).)*the(?:(?!<\/?p[^<]*>).)*?quick(?:(?!<\/?p[^<]*>).)*?brown(?:(?!<\/?p[^<]*>).)*?<\/p>
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lJ4uX9/1)

Answer (score 0):

This expression `^<p>.*The.*quick.*brown.*</p>\$` worked for me:

```
 [root@fedora ~]# grep "^<p>.*The.*quick.*brown.*</p>\$" test1.txt
<p><span style="font-size:16px"><strong>The quick brown &nbsp;</strong></span><strong><span style="font-size:16px">fox jumps.</span></strong></p>
<p><strong>The quick brown &nbsp;</strong></span><strong><span style="font-size:16px">fox jumps.</span></strong></p>
<p>The quick brown &nbsp;</strong></span><strong><span style="font-size:16px">fox jumps.</p>
[root@fedora ~]#
```

Comment: Unfortunately string is part of more text with nested HTML tags, your solution just matches my entire field text up to higher <p></p> tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in any editor (say notepad++) or javascript or any PCRE engine with `g`, `m`, `i` modifiers to match:

```
^<p>.*?the.*?quick.*?brown.*?<\/p>$
```

Used `.*` instead of `.+` because of your statement `they MIGHT be separated by something else`

and replace with `''` (empty string)

Comment: Unfortunately string is part of more text with nested HTML tags, your solution just matches my entire field text up to higher `<p></p>` tags.